# File upload php renombrar archivo

Tags: php, html

Me gustaria sobrescribir el archivo que suban por el id que tiene seria posible? Ya que asi pueden subir varios archivos pero por el nombre que tiene el archivo me gustaria que se quitara el nombre que suban ellos y automáticamente se renombre por el id del label.

**PHP**

```
 if(isset($_FILES['upload-file'])) {
        global $wp_filesystem;
        WP_Filesystem();
    $array = rearrange($_FILES['upload-file']);

    foreach ($array as $row){
      $name_file = $row['name'];
      $tmp_name = $row['tmp_name'];
      $path_parts = pathinfo($name_file);
      $ext = $path_parts['extension'];
      // saco el nombre del usuario
      global $current_user; wp_get_current_user();
      $username = $current_user->user_login;
      // directorio donde lo subo
      $content_directory = $wp_filesystem->wp_content_dir() . "uploads/archivos-subidos/$username/";
      $wp_filesystem->mkdir( $content_directory );

      move_uploaded_file( $tmp_name, $content_directory . " " . $name_file );
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
  <label for="upload-file-puntos_lic">  <i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
    <input name="upload-file[]" class="upload" type="file" multiple="multiple" id="upload-file-puntos_lic" />
```

Comment: Usa rename() antes de subirlo

Comment: Puedes hacerlo cuando lo mueves: `move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, '/ruta/nuevo_nombre.extension');`

Comment: Pero como le paso el nombre del id de cada uno

Comment: No se entiende demasiado bien de que `id` estas hablando. ¿tu donde lo ves o de donde lo sacas? ¿o te refieres a `id="upload-file-puntos_lic"`? ¿y que debe ocurrir si son varios archivos subidos? pues es un multiple

Comment: si son varios archivos el mismo id, y si me refiero al mismo id=upload-file-puntos_lic @masterguru

Comment: A ver, el id no sirve para mucho en peticiones $_POST, de hecho no sirve para nada, solo sirve el atributo `name=` pues el id no se pasa (el id va bien para cosas de javascript basicamente, pero no para formularios o peticiones POST que solo usan el atributo `name=`).  Por lo tanto plantéate más bien cambiar el `name=` que recibes solamente. O bien, supongo que es posible, le pasas otro input tipo hidden con name="id" y value="upload-file-puntos_lic" con el id que quieres cambiar en el mismo POST o submit del formulario, pero si son varios no se como lo vas a gestionar eso

Comment: Vale pues pongamos que le paso el name del archivo, pues si suben 2 quiero el mismo nombre @superguru

Comment: gracias, me has subido la autoestima, ahora soy "superguru"!  xD  (si hubieras puesto @masterguru lo hubiera visto antes!)... en fin.. a lo que ibamos... el array $_FILES almacena en su clave principal el texto que pongas en el atributo "name=" del 'input', por lo tanto, para sacárselo, prueba con `$nombre = key($_FILES);` y luego, si funciona bien, puedes usar esa variable $nombre para hacer el move_uploaded_file usándolo (pero si son varios recuerda agregarles un numerito o algo, sino solo quedara el ultimo pues se ira sobreescribiendo)

Comment: gracias @masterguru en probarlo te digo y disculpa por lo de super xD